# Perl Mechanize Error GETing (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: perl, mechanize

Consider this short piece of code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get("https://www.flightaware.com/live/airport/KCLE");
my $content = $mech->content();

print "$content\n";
```

It produces an error:

> Error GETing https://www.flightaware.com/live/airport/KCLE: Can't
> connect to [www.flightaware.com:443](http://www.flightaware.com:443) (Bad file descriptor) at line 6.

How can I improve upon this code for success?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https) installed?

Comment: The code works for me. Please check that the URL is reachable in the first place from the same system as you run this code by using other tools like curl to access it. Also make sure that any proxy variables you have set are correct. If other tools can access the site (i.e. it is not a connectivity problem in the first place) please provide information about your environment: OS, proxy settings, perl version, version of WWW::Mechanize ...